# Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x0FF0EA10 (ucrtbased.dll) в 2209_1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFFFFFFE4

Tags: c

наткнулся на проблему небольшую, хочу отсортировать массив символов предварительно динамически выделеным. Я в ф-цию передаю указатель на первый символ моего массива, но когда в ф-ции я хочу юзануть str[i] str[j] всё ломается
пробовал просто пройтись по массиву, оно работает
int i = 0;

```
int i = 0;
while(str[i] != '\0'){ printf("%c", str[i]); i++;) }
```

Вот код на Си.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void quickSort(char* str, int left, int right);

int main()
    {
    int n;
    printf("Enter size of string: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (n)+4);
    printf("Enter your string : ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    quickSort(str, 0, n);
    printf("Sorted string : \n %i", str);
    free(str);
    system("pause");
}

void quickSort(char* str, int left, int right)
{
    int i, j, p;
    i = left;
    j = right - 1;
    char tmp[100];
    while (i != j) {
        if ((strcmp(str[i], str[j]) > 0) != (i < j))
        {
            strcpy(tmp, str[i]);
            strcpy(str[i], str[j]);
            strcpy(str[j], tmp);

            p = i;
            i = j;

            if (p < j)
                j = p + 1;
            else j = p - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (i < j) j--;
            else j++;
        };
    };

    if (left < i - 1)
        quickSort(str ,left, i - 1);
    if (i + 1 < right)
        quickSort(str, i + 1, right);
}
```

[image: сама проблема]

Comment: Этот код даже не собирается... Строковые функции не могут использоваться таким образом..

Comment: А таким способом как тогда действовать?

Comment: `strcmp(str[i], str[j])` -  что это такое вообще? Это некомпилируемо.

Comment: Ну, допустим, код собирается - но со страшными warning'ами... @Денис, вы их видели? Вы разбирались, откуда они и что означают?